# set background image xcode6

Tags: background, swift, xcode6

Hope this is not to basic for you, how do I set a background image in Xcode 6.
I have my image saved as *.png saved it to supported files.
Just can't find the line of code I need.
Thank you.

Comment: Background image for what? Can you add more details? This question is pretty unclear. See [ask] and look at some other iOS/Cocoa questions for examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a background image in Xcode using swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049937/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-xcode-using-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the background image for the whole view or a UIButton or something else? For a UIButton, when you select it in the storyboard, the Attributes Inspector will have a drop down menu where you can set the background image.

If you want a something for the whole view, you are probably better off using a UIImageView as suggested by jmduke. In the Attributes Inspector there will be a drop down menu to set the image. Resize the UIImageView to fill your whole view, use constraints, etc. then select Arrange under the Editor menu and Send to Back. Your other UI elements will be on top of your background image.

Comment: Thank you,(next time ill be more specific when asking a question), thanks again exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead-set on making it a 'background image' (instead of creating a `UIImageView` directly), you'll want something along these lines:

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
yourview.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(UIImage(named:imageName))
```