# I change my BackgroundImage with a randomElement from an Array but its zoomed in and not fitting perfectly

Tags: arrays, swift, background, background-image

I have an array with my Image-names and a button. When I click on the button, the background-image schould get chaged. All is working but the pictures are a little bit zoomed and are not scaled to screen size.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var imagesArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]



    @IBAction func changeBackgroundImageButton_Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let randomImage = imagesArray.randomElement(){

            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: randomImage)!)
        }

    }

}
```

So what should I do that the background-images are not zoomed and scaled perfectly? Thanks!

Comment: use imageView instead of view.backgroundColor

Comment: could you send me the code please?

Comment: i sent you on your different account question ... you post a question .. then create new account and post another question from other account ?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36309946/4637057

Comment: Please check my solution, I've answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change background image of your view randomly, there is minor changes - that will update your background image and also it will not hide your button.

```
@IBAction func changeBackground_Tapped(_ sender: Any) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        UIImage(named: imagesArray.randomElement() ?? "1")?.draw(in: view.bounds)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        if let image = image {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
        }

}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is tested code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var imagesArray = ["1", "2", "3"]

        lazy var imageView:UIImageView = {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            imageView.backgroundColor = .red
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray.randomElement() ?? "1")
            return imageView
        }()

        @IBAction func changeBackground_Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray.randomElement() ?? "1")

            }


       private func setupView() {
            view.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            imageView.frame = view.bounds
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {


            super.viewDidLoad()
             setupView()


        }


    }
```

[image]